# when to use <build> plugin in maven pom.xml?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

In our project, we have configured jetty inside build plugin in pom, i want to understand configuration settings in pom/ what and all we can configure in pom.

what is `<build><plugin>` section in pom, when to use.

difficult to understand from tutorials because lot of different examples which is making confuse.

Please can somebody explain for the above in detail?

Answer (score 3):

Plugins defined in your buildsection plugins tag will be executed during the build of your project.

There are many plugins that do something with your build. 
For example the maven-compiler-plugin which allows you to set the Java version for your project.

```
 <build>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
  </build>
```

[a list of maven build plugins supported by maven itself](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/)

Comment: I have a multi pom project for api automation testing. One of the maven projects has automation tests. The build section of the project pom had only 1 plugin - maven surefire plugin with reference to a suite. The entire build tag was removed. Could you please tell me what this means ? thanks.